# How to create my own page layout with my own content type?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, content-type, page-layout

I want to create a Page Layout with following fields:

Title (textbox)
Summary(textbox)
Detail (textarea)
Image (this will be shown on top of the page at certain location which user will upload)

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you already have the Content Type?

Comment: No I don't have. Do I need to create some content type first?

Comment: If you want to do a Publishing Page Layout you will have to base it on a content type, existing or custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have been able to create content type and page layout using this tutorial
http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating a WebPart using Visual Studio.
By using Visual Studio - you can create a SharePoint Visual Web Part. This is like creating a normal .aspx page with it's .cs page for code behind. You can modify the look and feel of this page as you wish. you can even call data from SQL database or other SharePoint lists. After building the web part, you just deploy that web part to your farm. Then create a web-part page in your SharePoint site and insert your web part. Your web part will be stored in the custom folder from the web parts menu.

Comment: This answer is in danger of being flagged as "low-quality", can you please try to extend your answer with how this approach will be done? At least in a bit wider fashion :)

Comment: Hey Pieter, the poster is asking about how to create a content type and page layout. Why on earth do you suggest web parts?